# Creating an auth ConfigMap using python sdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to set a ConfigMap on my cluster using the python SDK. I'm planning on provisioning clusters on AWS EKS automatically, so want to be able to set the ConfigMaps using code.

I'm struggling to understand what format the data object should be in. I've been following the AWS EKS documentation and manually applied an auth configmap, and the output from `kubectl` looks like this:

```
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/dev-eks-workers-NodeInstanceRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```

I'm trying to set the structure in the following way (with an extra role for my local AWS user role):

```
body = client.V1ConfigMap()
body.api_version = 'v1'
body.kind = 'ConfigMap'
body.metadata = {
    'name': 'aws-auth',
    'namespace': 'kube-system'
}

body.data = {
  'mapRoles': [
    {
      'rolearn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/dev-eks-workers-NodeInstanceRole',
      'username': 'system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}',
      'groups': [
        'system:bootstrappers',
        'system:nodes'       
      ]
    },
    {
      'rolearn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/Admin',
      'username': 'admin',
      'groups': [
        'system:masters' 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

That code is rejected by the API. I guess its because the docs [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#create_namespaced_config_map) specify that data is to be a `dict(str, str)`

I tried a multi-line string, and while it does appear to set the configmap, it formatting is completely bust and it doesn't actually work with the roles defined.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: "\n- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/dev-apollo-eks-workers-NodeInstanceRole\n
    \ username: system:node:{EC2PrivateDNSName}\n  groups:\n    - system:bootstrappers\n
    \   - system:nodes\n\n- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Admin\n  username:
    admin\n  groups:\n   - system:masters\n    "
kind: ConfigMap
```

Can anyone give me an example of how I'm supposed to do this in python

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple ways, using this format works.

```
rolesString = ['- rolearn: ',
              f'{nodeRoleName}\n',
               '  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}\n',
               '  groups:\n',
               '    - system:bootstrappers\n',
               '    - system:nodes\n',
              f'- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::{accountId}:role/Admin\n',
               '  username: admin\n',
               '  groups:\n',
               '    - system:masters\n'
               ]

body.data = {
   'mapRoles': ''.join(rolesString)
}
```

Comment: Works for me as well. Was facing the issue with Python SDK, but with a multiline annotation instead.